# Have client send email using front JS and nodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I recently began working on a simple app to send emails. I'd like to use this in a website for a friends business. The goal, however, is to have a user of the website send an email to a specified address so that the business owner can receive clients for work.

I'm not quite sure whether or not that is **possible** given the current dependencies I'm using (it's just **nodemailer**). I'm currently able to receive test emails thru the app but the emails come only from my own email account (credentials saved in .env file). I can see the data I'm trying to send in the terminal, however. Is there something that I'm missing or another service that is needed in order to do what I'm looking to do? Any thoughts on how to proceed are appreciated, thanks!

```
require("dotenv").config();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

const PORT = 8080;

//data parsing
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth:
    {
        user: process.env.EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.PASSWORD
    }
});

app.post("/email", (req, res) =>{
    //data to handle
    let mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.senderEmail,
        to: "test@gmail.com",
        subject: req.body.subject,
        text: req.body.text
    };
    //sending email
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) =>{
        if(err){
            console.log("Error occured", err);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Data: ", req.body);
        }
    });
});
//display index.html
app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "views", "index.html"));
});
//Start server
app.listen(PORT, process.env.ID, () =>{
    console.log("Server is starting on PORT ", PORT);
});
```

**HTML file with small amount of jquery**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>App</h1>
    <form action="/email" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required><br>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="senderEmail" placeholder="Email" required><br>
        <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("form").on("submit", (e) =>
        {
            //stops default browser behaviour
            e.preventDefault();
            const email = $("#email").val().trim();
            const subject = $("#subject").val().trim();
            const text = $("#text").val().trim();

            const data = {email, subject, text};

            $.post("/email", data, () =>{ console.log("Server received our data");});
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should learn how smtp works. The rule is, if you send to an external domain, you need user name and password to do the relay. Sending directly won't work because of SPF/DMARC policies.

Comment: smtp came up a lot when researching this so this may be something I have to tinker with and understand a little better. But it is possible? That's comforting lol

Answer (score 1):

The user of a website can send email in 2 ways:

1. Send via direct email. You can have a `mailto:` before the email address in HTML.
2. Send a form request as you did, and have a proxy email like the one setup in your env that will then send the email to the business owner.

I highly doubt any email service will allow sending direct emails from Client id to business id, unless you have your own SMTP server setup with least security policies. This would be a huge security threat, by allowing server to send emails impersonating someone else!

Comment: I was able to set up a mailto (easy enough, really). Just want to make sure I'm reading this right: it's less of a security risk to run it through an smtp server? I wasn't planning on deploying until I had some kind of ability to vet whether or not a user's email address was legit or not regardless, it definitely seemed iffy to do that

Comment: Also, do you know of some of the better resources for getting started with smtp off the top of your head?

Comment: I'd suggest you not to setup SMTP servers knowing how it functions. The setup is a cumbersome job and maintaining it and enforcing security protocols require expertise. There are a good number of companies who have already setup servers, which you can use, but still that may not serve your purpose because of DMARC, DKIM and SPF policies. However you can play around with smtp servers, but I'd suggest not to put it to production. Here is a detailed resource on SMTP setup: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/create-maill-server-doc/latest/create-maill-server-doc.pdf